# How do I include a java 9 module at runtime?

Tags: java-9, java-module

I have a server kit that I'm trying to test on the java9 JDK (found [here](https://jdk9.java.net/download/), I'm using the 64-bit Linux version), however I'm encountering the following error shortly after startup:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:533)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:186)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:476)
```

The server kit starts without issue when using java8.  Somehow I need to tell the runtime system to include the `javax.xml.bind` module, however I'm new to java9 and don't know how to do this short of recompiling the entire server kit into a module and adding a dependency on the `javax.xml.bind` module.  Is there a way to resolve this error that doesn't require me to recompile the server kit into a module?

Comment: Can you try running with `--add-modules java.xml.bind`?

Comment: @Nicolai Thanks, that fixed the problem - if you open an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java EE modules are shipped with the JDK but [not resolved by default](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/) and *java.xml.bind* is one of them. In such cases they need to be included explicitly with `--add-modules`.

In your case, launch with `--add-modules java.xml.bind`.